# Handling a SQL Server Login error msg with VBA?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, odbc

I'm working in a VBA module for Access that queries linked tables, generates reports based off the data, and then uses a PDF printer to save the reports to disk. There's a timer in the primary form that will, every N seconds, run an Access query against a "JOBQUEUE" table to see if there are new jobs.

If the database server becomes unavailable, this operation will of course time out. The run-time error of 3051 is being logged, and the loop will try to continue. The loop can't finish, however, because the following error comes right after the VB Run-Time error;

Title is "Microsoft SQL Server Login", so it's not within VB as far as I can tell.

```
Connection Failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 53
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(Connect()).
Connection Failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not 
exist or access is denied.
```

In every forum & discussion I've found that mentions this error, the asker is concerned with the cause of the error. In this case, I can assume that the error is temporary, and that it needs to continue trying to connect because the installation is unattended. Access goes into a "Not Responding..." state when it's timing out against the DB, and that's OK too, if connection is restored before it goes into the MsgBox described above, it will pick up where it left off and soldier on.

Does anyone know of a way that I can either mute that msgbox, preferably programatically, but I'd take anything at this point that can be done remotely that isn't an RDP session.

**Edit: [Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGSZk.png)**

Comment: what about handling exceptions? it is not working?

Comment: @shibormot, I'm logging "Run-Time 3151:ODBC--connection to 'MyServerName' failed.", but this error is outside of VB as far as I can tell.  I've added a link to the image in the OP.

Comment: i mean do you trying to handle exceptions with `On Error` `GoTo` and `Resume` stuff? like described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb258159%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error I was getting was indeed not a run-time error that could be caught from code. Rather, it was SQL timing out after I already swallowed & dismissed time-outs in run-time in my VBA module.

The error does not seem to ever appear now that I have introduced a new timer that resets the loop that runs a query against my linked tables. It can't be logged & swallowed, but it can be prevented by being smarter about how I handle timeouts in run-time.