# how to solve time out connection to SQL server from access VBA

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba, sqlconnection

I am getting this error while trying to connect and link in tables from Access vba to SQL Server.

```
Connection Failed:
SQLState: '01000'
SQL Server Error: 53
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(Connect()).
Connection Failed:
SQLState: '08001'
SQL Server Error: 17
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not 
exist or access is denied.
```

I found solution on the link below, but i am not sure how to implement it. Any help would be apreciated.

[Handling a SQL Server Login error msg with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120143/handling-a-sql-server-login-error-msg-with-vba/15277960#15277960)

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error message to see from SQL server and as with any error message you need to read what it is saying and try and fix the cause.

The meat of it is in the message `SQL Server does not exist or access is denied.` This isn't mentioning a timeout, though it is probably taking a while before it fails.

So things to check are:

- Have you spelled the name of the server correctly
- Is there a firewall preventing access from seeing the server
- Are you connecting as a domain user who as permissions (trusted connection)
- Or have you provided the correct username and password (SQL credentials)

We don't have much information to go on, at the very least you need to edit your post to include your connection string (minus any passwords).